# PHP7: Issues updating iterated properties

Tags: php, php-7

Why does `foreach` in PHP7 iterate once again over an updated object property? Consider below, I just want to append "o" to all the first names.

```php
$people = [
    (object) ['first' => 'Bill', 'last' => 'Gates'],
    (object) ['first' => 'Steve', 'last' => 'Jobs']
];
foreach ($people as $i=>$p) {
    foreach ($p as $key=>$value) {
        echo "$key, $value<br>";
        if ($key == 'first') $p->first = $value . 'o';
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Outputs:

```
first, Bill
first, Billo
last, Gates

first, Steve
first, Steveo
last, Jobs
```

*Paste above into http://phpfiddle.org/ which uses PHP 7.0.22*

Comment: that is not what the output is: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/909acea393b9bc7c20686e50106ce5561b8cad80

Comment: @mickmackusa Your output is the same as his.

Comment: Thanks guys, it looks as if they fixed this in 7.1

Comment: @Barmar no, it isn't.  look again.  Changed to 7.0.2 and now I see the output: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/909acea393b9bc7c20686e50106ce5561b8cad80

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok, it looks like **PHP 7.1** solves this issue. I was testing on **PHP 7.0.22**.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug in the php version.

You can either upgrading your version, or use `array_map()` to avoid this bug.

You are attempting to perform a technique called `mapping` to concatenate specific element values.  `array_map()` is designed for this purpose.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7fc30270ff8b84a359ff351efd625803c8928eb1))

```
$people = [
    (object) ['first' => 'Bill', 'last' => 'Gates'],
    (object) ['first' => 'Steve', 'last' => 'Jobs']
];

foreach ($people as $i=>$p) {
    foreach ($p as $key=>$value) {
        echo "$key, $value<br>";
        if ($key == 'first') $p->first = $value . 'o';
    }
    echo "<br>";
}

echo "\n\n";

$people = [
    (object) ['first' => 'Bill', 'last' => 'Gates'],
    (object) ['first' => 'Steve', 'last' => 'Jobs']
];


$people=array_map(function($a){$a->first.='o'; return $a;},$people);
foreach ($people as $i=>$p) {
    foreach ($p as $key=>$value) {
        echo "$key, $value<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
first, Bill<br>first, Billo<br>last, Gates<br><br>first, Steve<br>first, Steveo<br>last, Jobs<br><br>

first, Billo<br>last, Gates<br><br>first, Steveo<br>last, Jobs<br><br>
```